# c# - Using Spire to convert pdf into excel through byte[]data in Stream (need to draw into pdf)

Tags: c#, itext, spire.xls

Good day, I am developing a feature which download excel based on the pdf layout set using iText. A byte[] data is generated from the iText which in this form "����hp�" if I Console.WriteLine it in LineEncoding.UTF8.GetString.

I want to load the byte[] data in pdf form, into Stream then convert it into excel using Spire library. So the user can download the excel with pdf layout without download and convert the pdf. Thank you for helping me!

//byte[] data which contained pdf layout using iText
`byte[] pdfData = _PDFService.CreatePDF(a, b);`
//Create Stream
`MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();`
//Write Stream with byte[] data
`pdfStream.Write(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length);`
`pdfStream.Position = 0;`

//Create a PdfDocument instance
`PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();`
//Load from Stream
`document.LoadFromStream(pdfStream);`
//Save to Excel
`document.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\...\output.xlsx", FileFormat.XLSX);`

Console output:
`Unhandled exception rendering component: The type initializer for 'spr⥪' threw an exception.`
`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'spr⥪' threw an exception.`

Comment: `The type initializer for 'spr⥪' threw an exception` - was there an inner exception which detailed what the actual issue was?

Comment: "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform." Seems like the byte[]data cant write in pdf form, but previously I can use Convert.ToBase64String(data) to render in a pdf form and download it.

Answer (score 0):

> "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not
> supported on this platform."

Are you using Spire.PDF to convert PDF to Excel on a non-windows platform? If so, you can remove the dll of Spire.PDF from your program, then search and install the **Spire.Office for.NETStandard** package via Nuget (you can also type the command "Install-Package Spire.Officefor.NETStandard" in the Package Manager Console to install it), this package contains the features of Spire.PDF and it does not rely on System.Drawing.Common.